# Lightning page assignment to specific users

Tags: lightning-record-page, lightning-page, record-page-setting

**Goal**: I'm trying to implement a new lightning record page for accounts, and I want to only assign it to a small group of employees. I can't assign it to an entire profile.

I'm aware that it's possible to assign a record page to a profile in a specific app, when the record is of a specific record type. However, I wish to assign the record page to specific users, or perhaps only to users where their "department" field has a certain value. I *could* create a new profile and only assign it to the chosen users, however the org has a lot of profiles already, so I need to avoid additional profiles.

Is anyone aware of a way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 2):

One solution is to edit the existing lighting record page. Add the components that the targeted audience should see, and then provide an advanced filter for each of those components, such that they will only be visible for them. For the existing components, that you wish to hide, add the "reverse" filter.

On each component:

1. Under component visibility, select "Add filter"
2. Choose advanced
3. Under "Field" click "Select"
4. Select User, and then the desired field to use.

This technique makes it possible to only show components for a small group of people without having to create new profiles.

Answer (score 0):

If this were a custom VisualForce page, you'd create a group and add each of the members you want to assign it to. You'd also create a permission set for the controller and page and associate it the the Group. However, we're talking about a Lightning page which doesn't have an Apex Controller. Consequently, I'm not entirely certain if the same strategy will work.

If you created an App that used the Lightning Page, then you could assign the Page as the default page for users with profile who use that App, then create a permission set to use the app which you assign to the Group. That might be another approach.

What it sounds like you essentially want to do is override the default page for these particular users so they'll use the new page instead of the default page. I've not seen this particular use case addressed in Lightning Documentation that I'm aware of without some kind of record type being involved.

@Andreas86 seems to have provided the best solution. If possible, I would still use Groups and membership in the Group as a visibility requirement for what component will or will net be seen. If you want Components to appear in different locations, you can duplicate them on a page and apply different visibility filters to each one such that a user will never see both.

Comment: I don't see an option to filter on group membership. Am I missing something? I see an option to filter on permissions. I could then assign a permission set to the selected employees, and filter on that. But I feel like it's more straight forward to just filter on user fields directly in the page setup.